# whats the process to check unique value mysql

Tags: mysql

See we have one table with **unique** key on one field,
now whenever we are **inserting** any record,**how mysql checking that that field value is exist** in table or not?

whats the logic here?

its internally fires queries to check that that value is exist in table ? I think thats not possible.

here unique filed can be any id,email,username anything

Answer (score 1):

MySQL creates index for primary and unique keys. So it checks index to see that new inserting value is unique actually. Since it is checking index, it does not hurt performance.

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Well it has to find the record in the index anyway when you inserting a value in order to write the data and to update all the indexes with your new value. Not much trouble to read that location and compare it to the new values.

so yes it just runs your query.

Comment: but whats the logic? whats the background process?

Comment: i don't think you will get a simole answer to this question, there are a couple of books dedicated specifically to mysql server internals, then of course you could always go crazy and look at the actual source code.